# Why I can not ssh to hostname:port

Tags: ssh

Why can't I specify the port with host like in http eg. ssh 127.0.0.1:2222?
Somehow it feels like normal way but at least OpenSSH client does not understand that.

Comment: Please consult `man ssh`.

Answer (score 3):

`ssh.c` does not contain code that supports that; [the code](https://anongit.mindrot.org/openssh.git) that reads the host only looks for `host` or `user@host` forms:

```
    if (ac > 0 && !host) {
            if (strrchr(*av, '@')) {
                    p = xstrdup(*av);
                    cp = strrchr(p, '@');
                    if (cp == NULL || cp == p)
                            usage();
                    options.user = p;
                    *cp = '\0';
                    host = xstrdup(++cp);
            } else
                    host = xstrdup(*av);
            if (ac > 1 && !opt_terminated) {
                    optind = optreset = 1;
                    goto again;
            }
            ac--, av++;
    }
```

The `host:port` form used by some programs is not the only way; [`telnet`](http://man.openbsd.org/telnet) for example uses `host port` as does [`nc`](http://man.openbsd.org/nc). The even older programs `rsh` and `rlogin` do not appear to allow the port to be specified. This choice is up to the author of the program, and for `ssh` `host:port` was not used.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I meant to ask, wheather there is some reason other than just a choice of the developers. Host:port feels so obvious to me.

Answer (score 0):

OpenSSH does not support `host:port` format. If you want to specify a port to SSH into, use `-p` option.

```
ssh -p 2222 ibug@example.com
```